# OPOS and Microsoft .NET, unable to run sample application

Tags: c#, .net, printing, opos

How can I fix this error?

[image]

[Source for the test application](http://monroecs.com/posfordotnet/opos_dotnet.htm)

Am i missing something?

Comment: Did you have registered the COM component? (regsvr32 oposlibraryname.dll)

Comment: @Steve, did not. the two lib i will install?

Comment: Did you install the Common Control Objects? if not you can do so from [here](http://monroecs.com/oposccos_current.htm).

Answer (score 1):

The error seems caused by missing information in the registry to resolve the interface for the library that control the POS device.
Usually these COM libraries have a setup program that takes care of the needed registration.
In lack of this, you could try to register manually the libraries with

```
regsvr32 libraryname.dll
```

Where, in place of `libraryname.dll`, write the effective name of yours dll.
And remember to do this also on the deployment machines.

Of course, as pointed by JamieHennerley in its answer, the Platform target of your application should match the same bitness of the library

Comment: I tried it to install but it gives me error dll was loaded but the entry point dllregisterserver was not found

Comment: Could you tell me the exact product name and where did you get these libraries? Did you have example code to interact with these libraries?

Comment: yeah its in the link, thats there sample app but it got error

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem in the MCS sample application.
I fixed this by registering the CCO (i.e. regsvr32 OPOSPOSPrinter.ocx).
Make sure that the version of OPOSPOSPrinter.ocx is greater than or equal to the .NET assembly.
In the sample application, I think the .NET assemblies are version for 1.12.

Comment: One easy way I found to do this is to install the Common Control Objects from here: http://monroecs.com/oposccos_current.htm. Make sure you also select the x86 build.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio - Project Properties - Build tab - platform target =X86

That should hopefully fix the error